# Mathematica 12.1 Crashes when making large partitions of an image

Tags: graphics, image-processing, crash

I need to partition an image of dimension 1000 x 1000 for 200 x 200 parts. In order to do so I am using `ImagePartition` function but when I try to display the output mathematica 12.1 crashes without saying anything. I have an 8GB RAM machine. How can I resolve this issue or is there any way to export my output to another file format in expanded form. I tried `Export` but it does the same while doing this even when exporting to a pdf format.
The  code I am using is [image]

````
imgParts = ImagePartition[img, 5];
Grid[DominantColors[#, All, {"Color", "Count"}] & /@ imgParts, Frame -> All]```
````

Comment: Can you add the specific code you are using to your question? There isn't quite enough detail to be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Ah, so you are splitting the image into 5x5 pixel subimages. I was under the impression that you wanted 200x200 pixel subimages. You could consider using `ParallelMap`, and you will want to `Flatten` `imgParts`. This code (specifically, `DominantColors`) is destined to take a long time as you are running it on 40,000 elements.

Comment: To add some detail, memory usage does not appear to be the limiting factor here, CPU time does. On my four core computer, it took 4 minutes to do `ParallelMap[DominantColors[#, 1, {"Color", "Count"}] &, 
 Flatten[imgParts]]`. As you are getting `All` dominant colors instead of `1`, it may take much more time.

Comment: Why do you want to do this computation and what will it achieve? The Grid is going to be huge and will crash the front-end.

Comment: If you just need the single most common colour in every non-overlapping 5x5 block, then this will near-instantly produce an image where every 5x5 block is represented as a single pixel `Image[BlockMap[First[Commonest[Flatten[#, 1]]] &, ImageData[img], {5, 5}]]`. If you want overlap /  sliding window then  use `CommonestFilter`.

Comment: I want to access and use the counts for further analysis. How can I do that without having shown the output of grid of dominant color and counts?

Comment: @AtiqueKhan `bm = BlockMap[DominantColors[Image@#, All, {"Color", "Count"}] &, 
   ImageData[img], {5, 5}];` then access the blocks with for example `bm[[11,10]]`. You don't need to show any output.